# React state contains correct data initially but is overwritten by previous value

Tags: reactjs

i have a state variable which is initially set to null. After getting data from server i update its state. In doing so.. it loads correct data for items with different ids. however on opening the item that was previously opened... sets the state with correct value. however it then overwrites the state value with previous opened item.

I am not sure what going wrong.

Below is the code,

```
class Items extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        item_details: null,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
       this.load_item_details();  
    }

    componentDidUpdate(PrevProps) {
        this.load_item_details();
    }

    load_item_details = () => {
    const file_name = 'item_details.json';
    client.get_item_details_file(this.props.item_id, file_name, 'json')
        .then((request) => {
            this.setState({item_details: request.response});
        })};
    }
```

Could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Edit: This is how the output looks the first time i run the application clicking some item for the first time.

[image]

Now when i click another item with id 8 it  outputs correct data (from output state with array 25) however it is replaced with previous item details (from output state with array 806).

[image]

Comment: How do you use `Items` component? Does `this.props.item_id` change between `load_item_details` calls?

Comment: yes this.props.item_id changes on clicking different item it loads details related to it. and if i remove componentdidupdate lifecycle it displays correct state after page refresh. But i want it to display correct data without page refresh.

Comment: You should compare `PrevProps.item_id` and `this.props.item_id` inside `componentDidUpdate` and call `this.load_item_details()` only when `item_id` changes. Also `console.log(this.props.item_id)` inside `load_item_details` to track `item_id` changes.

Comment: @UjinT34: edited the question. please have a look. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `item_id inside method 1` and `item_id inside method 8` in the second log. Looks like you send two simultaneous requests with different ids. Since data for item_id=1 is much larger than data for item_id=8 it arrives later and overwrites everything. Try to call `load_item_details` only when needed and use some flag to block simultaneous requests.

```
...
this.state = {
    item_details: null,
    isLoading: false,
};
...
componentDidUpdate(PrevProps) {
    if (PrevProps.item_id !== this.props.item_id) this.load_item_details();
}
...
load_item_details = () => {
    if (this.state.isLoading) return;
    const file_name = 'item_details.json';
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    client.get_item_details_file(this.props.item_id, file_name, 'json')
    .then((request) => {
        this.setState({item_details: request.response, isLoading: false});
    })};
}
```

Note that this code will not react to any changes to `item_id` while `load_item_details` is fetching data. And it will break on error inside `client.get_item_details_file`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a typo on your code:

```
    load_item_details = () => {
const file_name = 'item_details.json';
client.get_item_details_file(this.props.item_id, file_name, 'json')
    .then((request) => {
        this.setState({item_detail: request.response});
    })};
}
```

It should be `this.setState({item_details: request.response})`

Comment: its a typo...although i mean the state value is overwritten by previous value.